# PHP / PostgreSQLのメモリ解放

Tags: php, postgresql

PHP / PDOドライバのキャッシュ機能について

#### 環境

- PostgreSQL9.4
- IDIORM
- Paris

PostgreSQLは検索結果をキャッシュしてしまうようで、メモリリークしてしまいます。
大規模な`Select`を行った後は、どうすれば解放してもられるんでしょうか。
できればソース(参考文献)と共に、教えてください。

Comment: 「メモリリーク」はどうやって確認しましたか？確認方法と結果を質問に追記してください

Comment: すみません、今環境が手元にないのでログ等は出せません。
でもメモリーリークなのは間違いないです。

Comment: @omarun 確認方法の方は、どのように行われたのでしょう？　解決したと思ったら別の事象だったという事を防ぐためにも提示していただけるとより状況をより近づけられるので回答しやすくなると思います。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

間違いなくメモリリークしていると判断できる根拠があるのであれば、該当部分(PostgreSQL?IDIORM?Paris?)のデベロッパにその根拠を添えてバグ報告しましょう。

ここでいくら質問してもプロダクトのバグが直ることはまずありません。

Comment: ことの経緯を説明すると、
PHPのプログラムを動かしてみると、標準出力にエラーが出て、具体的な内容は覚えていませんが、
メモリリークの旨のエラーログが記載してありました。(ちゃんと読んだので間違いないです。)

そこで、PMに報告し、調べてもらったところ、
「PostgreSQLはSELECTすると、結果をキャッシュしてしまうみたいだ。でも解決策はわからなかった。そっちでも調べてくれるか？」
ということだったので、こちらでもいろいろ調べてみたものの、わからなかったので質問しました。

なので、PostgreSQLがキャッシュするのがバグなのか、仕様なのかはわかりませんでした。
可能だったらPostgreSQLの開発元に確認してみようと思います。

ありがとうございました。

Answer (score 1):

Idiorm には SELECT 結果をキャッシュする機構があるようです。デフォルトでは無効になっているようですが、もし有効にしているのであればこれが原因の可能性は高いかと。

- [PHPの薄いDBライブラリ「Idiorm」を使ってみた - Qiita](http://qiita.com/naga3/items/87fef230ac86aeec1eea)
- [Configuration — Idiorm documentation](http://idiorm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/configuration.html#query-caching)

今更かもしれませんが、参考までに。